# Why use tagQuery() in shiny apps?

Tags: r, shiny, htmlwidgets

I have read this [article on tagQuery](https://rstudio.github.io/htmltools/articles/tagQuery.html) and was left wondering what could be the practical use in a shiny app.

Is it to modify a tag on the server side in a way similar to `shinyjs::addClass()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it’s mostly useful when you need to modify or extract parts of a
potentially deeply nested HTML structure. Such a need may arise in particular
in cases where you don’t have control over creating the original structure,
but rely on a package to do that for you.

For a real example, [this old answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58411077/4550695)
could benefit from using `tagQuery()`.

As the setup, we have a dynamically generated menu. There, we want to add
an `id` attribute to the `ul` element inside, in order to be able to later
target that element with JavaScript.

```r
library(shinydashboard, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(htmltools)

tabs_list <- lapply(1:2, function(x) {
  menuSubItem(text = paste("tab", x))
})

menu <- menuItem("test_tabs", tabs_list)
print(menu)
#> <li class="treeview">
#>   <a href="#">
#>     <span>test_tabs</span>
#>     <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right" role="presentation" aria-label="angle-left icon"></i>
#>   </a>
#>   <ul class="treeview-menu" style="display: none;" data-expanded="test_tabs">
#>     <li>
#>       <a href="#">
#>         <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right" role="presentation" aria-label="angle-double-right icon"></i>
#>         tab 1
#>       </a>
#>     </li>
#>     <li>
#>       <a href="#">
#>         <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right" role="presentation" aria-label="angle-double-right icon"></i>
#>         tab 2
#>       </a>
#>     </li>
#>   </ul>
#> </li>
```

Here’s the original approach:

```r
menu_orig <- menu
menu_orig$children[[2]] <- tagAppendAttributes(menu_orig$children[[2]], id = "test_tabs")
```

With `tagQuery()` this would be easier to understand and more robust:

```r
menu_tq <- tagQuery(menu)$find("ul")$addAttrs(id = "test_tabs")$allTags()

# Check that we got the same result
identical(format(menu_orig), format(menu_tq))
#> [1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd like ta add up a few aspects on @MikkoMarttila answer (too long for a comment):

`tagQuery` provides you with the possibility of manipulating HTML tags from within R (No JS required).

Please see [this section](https://unleash-shiny.rinterface.com/htmltools-overview.html#htmltools-modern) from *Outstanding User Interfaces with Shiny* for a lot of great examples.

I recently gave a related answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71343768/how-can-i-make-a-shiny-app-w3c-compliant/71348276#71348276), which is showing how to make a shiny app w3c-compliant - accordingly `tagQuery` can help making your app production ready (regarding the UI).

Also note that `tagQuery` can be used dynamically inside of / along with `renderUI` calls - please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71012300/modifying-the-color-border-of-valuebox-in-r-shiny/71015653#71015653) for an example.